# Can't access object in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this code in services:

```
      return {
          getReport: function(data){
            var request = $resource(getResourcePath('report'));
            return request.get(data, function(response) {
                return response;
            }).$promise;
          }
      }
```

and this code is in my controller:

```
    ReportService.getReport(customStruct).then(function(response){
        console.log("respo", response);
        $scope.reportData = {response}
    });
  
    console.log("$scope1", $scope)
    console.log("$scope2", $scope.reportData)
```

but when I try to access `$scope.reportData`, I get `undefined`. Here's a screenshot of `$scope1` and `$scope2` output:

[image]

Why can't I access `$scope.reportData` object? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: `promise` is not resolved when you console log `$scope.reportData ` as `promises` are async.

Comment: try to console it inside your callback

Comment: `$scope` was already assigned with response object when `console.log("$scope1", $scope)` data can be seen. So `promise` was suppose to be resolved right?

Comment: `console.log("$scope1", $scope)` logs an actual object, not its snapshot. If it was updated since then, you can inspect it with all modifications that was done to it. Never trust logged objects. You need to convert them to strings to get their state at the moment when they were logged.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're dealing with the classic "where's my data" async question. Angular and JavaScript return [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from http calls. A promise is a bit like a box that Angular hands you and says "when the data comes back, I'll put it in this box." The problem is that if you try to access the data in the box, it won't be there (inlcuding your console.log).

If you must have the data before your view loads, consider using the [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) feature of $routeProvider (ng-route) or $stateProvider (ui-router). For example:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.reports', {
    url: 'reports/reports.html',
    ...
    resolve : {
       reportData : function(ReportService) {
            return ReportService.getReport(customStruct);
       }
    }
});
```

Then in your controller, specify reportData as a depenedency:

```
.controller('someController', ['$scope',
                                'reportData',
                                function($scope, reportData){
    $scope.reportData = reportData;
}]);
```

This forces Angular to wait for reportData to resolve before loading the view. However, there is a dark side: if the response takes more than a few milliseconds to return, the [UI may feel unresponsive](http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/02/angularjs-pitfalls-using-ui-routers-resolve/).

A couple of final notes to point out. This line:

```
    $scope.reportData = {response}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by wrapping the response in an object. Lastly this line:

```
        return request.get(data, function(response) {
            return response;
        })
```

You might want to consider returning response.data instead of response (which contains headers and some other cruft you might not need if the response was successful).

Good luck!